# How to move one database in influx to another server?

Tags: influxdb

I want to move one database from one server to another

I followed this guide: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/administration/config/

But when I restored metadata I wiped out all my usernames and passwords with new db.

Do I need to restore metadata at all and is there are way to restore it without wiping out existing databases?

Comment: Can you list out the exact sequence of commands that you ran and what output you got.

Answer (score -1):

Metadata should not be imported when importing one database to an existing server.